# Do iPhone X cases fit on the iPhone XS?

Tags: iphone, case

Does anyone know whether the iPhone X and the iPhone XS have the exact same measurements as far as cases are concerned?

I know that the measurements shown on the [Apple iPhone compare webpage](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/) are the same, but what about the measurements of the camera? Apple does not show this on their website.

Let's suppose, that the X and the XS have the exact same measurements, then every iPhone X case should fit on the XS, correct?

But even if there is the slightest difference between them, there could be some iPhone X cases that can't fit iPhone XS.

Comment: I asked this exact question in my local Apple Store two days ago and they confirmed that Apple-made iPhone X cases will fit the XS.

Comment: @NimeshNeema your edit to the title reduced the readability and changed what it actually says. In this case it now reads if an iPhone X case will fit an iPhone X, which is not what OP is asking. Please revert it back to the original title, which was perfectly clear and grammatically correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Various sources on the Web affirm that iPhone X and iPhone XS are near identical in dimensions and cases for iPhone X should fit iPhone XS.

However, there are also various reports pointing out specific cutouts applicable to certain cases.

Like, if the camera opening on the iPhone XS is noticeably larger, so if you have a case with a **very tight** fighting camera opening, your iPhone XS may not fit. One point outs that the placement of microphone vent is slightly different between the two phones.

The various reviews are shared below for reference:

1. From the [Q&A](https://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/product/MTFA2ZM/A/will-iphone-x-cases-fit-on-the-iphone-xs/Q9DA4ATUYTX9KCCFT) on Apple Online store:

> Yes! They have same dimensions and buttons location. So all your cases from iPhone X will perfectly fit iPhone XS.

2. Reddit thread, from [/r/iphone](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/), [PSA: iPhone X Cases Will NOT Fit XS](https://www.reddit.com/r/iphone/comments/9gzklf/psa_iphone_x_cases_will_not_fit_xs/)

> Just noticed this in MKBHD's review: https://youtu.be/YAF9BWpzwvI?t=2m7s
>   The camera opening is noticeably larger. If you're upgrading from an X to XS, you'll need new cases.

3. iMore, [Will your old case fit the new iPhone XR, iPhone XS, and iPhone XS Max?](https://www.imore.com/will-your-old-case-fit-new-iphone-xr-iphone-xs-and-iphone-xs-max)

> The iPhone XS is a refresh of last year's iPhone X, and appears to have the exact same design and dimensions. This means that you should be able to use your old iPhone X case with your iPhone XS. So all those great cases already available for the iPhone X are ripe for the picking!
>
> That being said, the microphone layout on the bottom of the iPhone XS is slightly different than the iPhone X, which means cases that have precise cutouts for those microphone holes in the iPhone X, may be slightly misaligned on an iPhone XS.

4. iPhone Hacks, [Will iPhone X Cases Fit the iPhone XS?](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2018/09/iphone-x-case-fit-iphone-xs.html)

> The answer is a resounding yes! The iPhone XS shares the same dimensions as the iPhone X and since all port locations are also the same, iPhone X cases will fit the iPhone XS just fine. The latter is 3gms heavier than the iPhone X but this difference is unlikely to create any issues for cases with a kickstand or a slim profile.

5. CNET, [Will my iPhone XS fit in a iPhone X case? Yes!](https://www.cnet.com/news/will-my-iphone-xs-fit-in-a-iphone-x-case-yes/)

> The two iPhones have the exact same height, width and depth.

6. MacRumors, [iPhone X Cases May Have Slightly Imperfect Fit on iPhone XS Due to New Camera Bump Dimensions](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/09/19/iphone-x-cases-may-not-perfectly-fit-iphone-xs/)

> While the iPhone X and iPhone XS have identical overall dimensions, a new report suggests that iPhone X cases may have a slightly imperfect fit on the iPhone XS due to very slight changes to the camera bump dimensions.
>
> [image]

---

**Note**: The official case design guidelines for devices from Apple are made available [here](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/). The linked [Accessory Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) containing precise measurements should soon get updated to include iPhone XS. If interested, you can go through the measurements to get a better idea of what aspects have changed between iPhone X and iPhone XS, and case analyze case compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the overview, that's exactly what I was worried about.

Comment: The Xs camera is slightly bigger than the X. So you can't use a X case on a Xs, but you can use a Xs case on a X, although there's a slight gap around the camera bulge. MHBHD's unboxing video demonstrates this.

Comment: The #1 "Yes! They have same dimensions and buttons location. So all your cases from iPhone X will perfectly fit iPhone XS." quotation does not exist at the Apple Q&A link… The only answer there is "it may fit...from what I heard, the camera housing on the xs, is very slightly larger than x....the case may have trouble fitting over the camera"

Answer (score 8):

I've just watched [this YouTube video by MKBHD](https://youtu.be/YAF9BWpzwvI?t=1m55s) where he reviewed the XS and XS Max and he shows that the X case will fit onto the XS but that the camera lens does not align properly - the new XS camera bump is smaller, so there is a slight gap to one side (not uniformly around unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In the video he shows that the Xs case fits onto the X (with a slight gap on one side). So the camera of the Xs is slightly larger, and some X cases won't fit on the Xs.

Comment: MacRumours have a great little article just posted which outlines the sizing issue around the camera "bump". https://www.macrumors.com/2018/09/19/iphone-x-cases-may-not-perfectly-fit-iphone-xs/?utm_source=osx&utm_medium=push&utm_campaign=front

Answer (score -2):

Yes. I have an Apple leather iPhone X case that fits my iPhone XS perfectly.